# Android JB 4.2.2 Compile Error

Tags: android, linux, makefile, android-source

Hi Guys im building the aosp for a custom board and i cant seem to figure out this error - any helps greatly appreciated Thanks!!!

```
host C: mkfs.ubifs <= external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/hashtable/hashtable.c
host C: mkfs.ubifs <= external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/hashtable/hashtable_itr.c
Export includes file: external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/Android.mk -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkfs.ubifs_intermediates/export_includes
host Executable: mkfs.ubifs (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkfs.ubifs_intermediates/mkfs.ubifs)
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/liblzo2.so when searching for -llzo2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llzo2
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libuuid.so when searching for -luuid
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
build/core/host_executable.mk:19: recipe for target 'out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkfs.ubifs_intermediates/mkfs.ubifs' failed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkfs.ubifs_intermediates/mkfs.ubifs] Error 1
```

---

```
Install: out/host/linux-x86/bin/mke2fs
Import includes file: out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/mkfs.ubifs_intermediates/import_includes
host C: mkfs.ubifs <= external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c
In file included from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.h:54:0,
                 from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:23:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/ubifs.h: In function ‘ubifs_idx_branch’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/ubifs.h:426:55: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  return (struct ubifs_branch *)((void *)idx->branches +
                                                       ^
In file included from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.h:55:0,
                 from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:23:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/key.h: In function ‘key_write’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/key.h:148:12: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memset(to + 8, 0, UBIFS_MAX_KEY_LEN - 8);
            ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c: In function ‘prepare_node’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:712:43: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  crc = ubifs_crc32(UBIFS_CRC32_INIT, node + 8, len - 8);
                                           ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c: In function ‘write_leb’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:731:13: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memset(buf + len, 0xff, c->leb_size - len);
             ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c: In function ‘do_pad’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:759:13: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memset(buf + len, 0xff, alen - len);
             ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:762:6: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  buf += alen;
      ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:777:43: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   crc = ubifs_crc32(UBIFS_CRC32_INIT, buf + 8,
                                           ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:781:14: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   memset(buf + UBIFS_PAD_NODE_SZ, 0, pad_len);
              ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c: In function ‘add_node’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:958:17: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memcpy(leb_buf + offs, node, len);
                 ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:959:17: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memset(leb_buf + offs + len, 0xff, ALIGN(len, 8) - len);
                 ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:959:24: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memset(leb_buf + offs + len, 0xff, ALIGN(len, 8) - len);
                        ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c: In function ‘add_dent_node’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:1124:2: warning: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 4 has type ‘ino_t’ [-Wformat=]
  dbg_msg(3, "%s ino %lu type %u dir ino %lu", name, inum,
  ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:1124:2: warning: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 6 has type ‘ino_t’ [-Wformat=]
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c: In function ‘add_file’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:1224:23: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
    ret = read(fd, buf + bytes_read,
                       ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c: In function ‘add_idx_node’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:1643:17: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memcpy(leb_buf + offs, node, len);
                 ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:1644:17: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memset(leb_buf + offs + len, 0xff, ALIGN(len, 8) - len);
                 ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:1644:24: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memset(leb_buf + offs + len, 0xff, ALIGN(len, 8) - len);
                        ^
In file included from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.h:54:0,
                 from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:23:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c: In function ‘main’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/ubifs.h:412:60: warning: ‘child_cnt’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  return UBIFS_IDX_NODE_SZ + (UBIFS_BRANCH_SZ + c->key_len) * child_cnt;
                                                            ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.c:1668:6: note: ‘child_cnt’ was declared here
  int child_cnt, j, level, blnum, boffs, blen, blast_len, err;
      ^
host C: mkfs.ubifs <= external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/crc16.c
host C: mkfs.ubifs <= external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/crc32.c
host C: mkfs.ubifs <= external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/devtable.c
In file included from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.h:54:0,
                 from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/devtable.c:47:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/ubifs.h: In function ‘ubifs_idx_branch’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/ubifs.h:426:55: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  return (struct ubifs_branch *)((void *)idx->branches +
                                                       ^
In file included from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.h:55:0,
                 from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/devtable.c:47:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/key.h: In function ‘key_write’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/key.h:148:12: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memset(to + 8, 0, UBIFS_MAX_KEY_LEN - 8);
            ^
host C: mkfs.ubifs <= external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c
In file included from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.h:54:0,
                 from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:23:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/ubifs.h: In function ‘ubifs_idx_branch’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/ubifs.h:426:55: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  return (struct ubifs_branch *)((void *)idx->branches +
                                                       ^
In file included from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.h:55:0,
                 from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:23:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/key.h: In function ‘key_write’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/key.h:148:12: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memset(to + 8, 0, UBIFS_MAX_KEY_LEN - 8);
            ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c: In function ‘pack_pnode’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:219:22: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  uint8_t *addr = buf + UBIFS_LPT_CRC_BYTES;
                      ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:236:22: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  crc = crc16(-1, buf + UBIFS_LPT_CRC_BYTES,
                      ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c: In function ‘pack_nnode’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:252:22: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  uint8_t *addr = buf + UBIFS_LPT_CRC_BYTES;
                      ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:268:22: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  crc = crc16(-1, buf + UBIFS_LPT_CRC_BYTES,
                      ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c: In function ‘pack_ltab’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:284:22: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  uint8_t *addr = buf + UBIFS_LPT_CRC_BYTES;
                      ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:293:22: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  crc = crc16(-1, buf + UBIFS_LPT_CRC_BYTES,
                      ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c: In function ‘pack_lsave’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:308:22: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  uint8_t *addr = buf + UBIFS_LPT_CRC_BYTES;
                      ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:315:22: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  crc = crc16(-1, buf + UBIFS_LPT_CRC_BYTES,
                      ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c: In function ‘create_lpt’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:432:5: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   p += c->pnode_sz;
     ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:484:6: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
    p += c->nnode_sz;
      ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:516:5: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   p += c->lsave_sz;
     ^
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/lpt.c:541:4: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  p += c->ltab_sz;
    ^
host C: mkfs.ubifs <= external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/compr.c
In file included from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.h:54:0,
                 from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/compr.c:33:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/ubifs.h: In function ‘ubifs_idx_branch’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/ubifs.h:426:55: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  return (struct ubifs_branch *)((void *)idx->branches +
                                                       ^
In file included from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs.h:55:0,
                 from external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/compr.c:33:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/key.h: In function ‘key_write’:
external/mtd-utils/mkfs.ubifs/key.h:148:12: warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
  memset(to + 8, 0, UBIFS_MAX_KEY_LEN - 8);
```

and then from the .mk file

```
###########################################################
## Standard rules for building an executable file.
##
## Additional inputs from base_rules.make:
## None.
###########################################################

LOCAL_IS_HOST_MODULE := true
ifeq ($(strip $(LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS)),)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := EXECUTABLES
endif
ifeq ($(strip $(LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX)),)
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(HOST_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX)
endif

include $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/binary.mk

$(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE): $(all_objects) $(all_libraries)
    $(transform-host-o-to-executable)
```

Error in my compile for android JB 4.2.2

Comment: the SOC for the board is i.mx6DL

Comment: Welcome to Satckoverflow. Post the code snippets on which you are getting above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binary needs `liblzo2.so` and `libuuid.so`, but these libraries for the target board have not been built. Maybe you are missing some setup, e.g.

```
$ sudo apt-get install uuid-dev liblzo2-dev
```

check http://www.slideshare.net/noritsuna/how-to-build-android-for-arm-chip-boards slide #44.